# Metadata in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest, metadata, reverse-engineering, aapt

Is there any way to get the meta-data declared in AndroidManifest.xml from **apk**?

PS: Not programmatically.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data
  android:name="password"
  android:value="abc123" />
```

I had tried to use aapt d badging /apkpath.

But what I got is only the package, versionCode, versionName, platformBuildVersionName, sdkVersion, targetSdkVersion, uses-permission and application-label.

Answer (score 0):

Pro grammatically you can read meta data like this

```
try {
ApplicationInfo app = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
Bundle bundle = app.metaData;
String myApiKey = bundle.getString("password");
} catch (Exception e) {
 // handle exception
}
```

Comment: but what I want to know is is it possible to get it from .apk file?

Comment: @lohjyhyeong you can use `aapt dump --include-meta-data badging file.apk` to extract meta-data from AndroidManifest.xml.

If you can open this question again I can submit this as the answer.